# Pinpoint archive file from a list of archive files where the target file is zipped

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I have a directory structure like this -

```
./Archive1
./Archive1/Archive2
./Archive1/Archive3
```

In each directory there are many `tar` files. Say for example (don't go with the name, they are just for example) -

```
Archive1
├── Archive2
│   ├── tenth.tar.gz
│   └── third.tar.gz
├── Archive3
│   ├── fourth.tar.gz
│   └── sixth.tar.gz
├── fifth.tar.gz
├── first.tar.gz
└── second.tar.gz
```

Now I have a file `file.txt`, that could reside in any tar file. I need a command that would give me the output as which tar file have my input file (`file.txt`) and also the absolute path of the tar file.

So for example if `test.txt` is in `sixth.tar.gz`. The output will be `sixth.tar.gz` and `./Archive1/Archive3/`

Currently I have this command, but the drawback of the command is, it is listing all the tar files -

```
find . -maxdepth "3" -type f -name "*.tar.gz" -printf [%f]\\n -exec tar -tf {} \; | grep -iE "[\[]|file.txt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each tar file, you can run `tar | grep`, and if there is a match, print the tar file's name. One way to do this is by running a shell command for each tar file. For a small number of files, and if performance is not too important, this might be good enough and it's fairly straightforward.

```
find . -maxdepth "3" -type f -name "*.tar.gz" -exec sh -c 'tar tf {} | grep -iEq "[\[]|file.txt" && echo {}' \;
```

So for example if `test.txt` is in `sixth.tar.gz`, the output will be `./Archive1/Archive3/sixth.tar.gz`.